# JPA: @OneToOne creates an implicit unique constraint with a randomly generated name. Is there any way to spcify that name in code using annotations?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, constraints

In a Java class, I have this property

```
@OneToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private MyPropertyClass myProperty;
```

which not only creates a foreign key constraint, but a unique constraint also. This is the Hibernate DDL Schema output:

```
Hibernate: create table [...]
Hibernate: alter table [...] add constraint UK_nk1hqjkd7ln1f9a2pju1yy8ay  unique (myProperty)
```

Is there *any* way to specify the name of the unique constraint?

Comment: Firstly don't use JPA to update your tables. Secondly why do you want to use this constraint in code. It's meta data you should not need this.

Comment: @Shahzeb: This is how JPA constructs the tables, by creating the raw table and then by altering the table to add the constraints. As for your second question, I need to be able to extract a proper DDL Schema from the database, and I do not want the constraint names to be random gibberish, tbh.

Comment: @Shahzeb using JPA or liquibase (which is safer) does not make any difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try `uniqueConstraints` attribute of `@Table` annotation in the class level.

```
@Table( name ="tablename " , uniqueConstraints={
       @UniqueConstraint(name="myconst", columnNames={"myProp"})
   })

public class MyEntity {

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade =     CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name="myProp")
private MyPropertyClass myProperty;

}
```

Comment: Not obvious but that actually makes sense, as it's one to one, implicitly the column must be unique.